Using all loopback IPs on OS X
I has service that binds random loopback IP on 127.0.0.0/8 subnet on demand (like 127.12.34.56).
It works fine on Linux but does not work on OS X.
Only solution I found was to make alias for each single address with ifconfig. But because I need all of 16,777,216 addresses and cannot modify source code, this not that case.

OS X:
% nc -l 127.12.34.56 1234
nc: Can't assign requested address


Linux:
$ nc -l 127.12.34.56 1234
# it works




Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
